# Image resource not accessible in Playground Xcode 7.2.1

Tags: xcode, swift, swift-playground

I'm having problems loading an image in swift playgrounds in Xcode 7.2.1

[image: Swift Playground Snapshot]

As above, repeated here

```
import UIKit

let image = UIImage(named: "sample")
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sample", ofType: "png")
```

file `sample.png` is located in the `Resources` folder of the playground.

Am I missing something?
Did something change?
Is this a bug in Xcode 7.2.1?

Comment: Hey, I rolled back your question to revision one, since ["answers do not belong in questions"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307946/was-this-rollback-edit-suggestion-appropriate/307947#307947).  If you have any questions, feel free to ping me in the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) chatroom.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image isn't in an asset catalog (or a PNG), you would need to pass the full file name into the UIImage `named` constructor:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "sample.jpg")
```

In `pathForResource`, your file type is wrong.  The extension of your image is `jpg`, not a `png`:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sample", ofType: "jpg")
```

Comment: Totally missed that typo in the second part, thanks!

Comment: From other examples it appeared that the `named:` versions worked in earlier Xcode. It is not well documented elsewhere, that I could find.

Comment: @bshirley I've only found that `name:` worked with images in an asset catalog (ex: having 1x, 2x, and 3x slices).  Any images copied to the bundle outside of an asset catalog would need the file extension, at least in my experience.

Comment: @bshirley update: After discussing this with a colleague, he mentioned that after iOS 4, `imageNamed` was changed to no longer require the extension in the name for .png files: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed:  But since you're using a jpg, it looks like the extension is still required.

Comment: hey @JAL can i use xyz.imageset in swift playground